# Expo issue when running app for the first time

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using Expo CLI to create my first react-native app, I installed Expo globally and npm modules too, but when I start my app using "expo start" or "npm start" the page give me this error *"Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Use the expo start command to start the CLI again."*
I tryed to install watchman but I can't install it, what can I do? I have Mac OS.

Comment: Try running "expo doctor". I don't think it will necessarily solve your problem but it's worth a shot to see what it says about the health of the pristine project you created.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the Expo CLI, by running:

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli && npm install -g expo-cli
```